# Is there any method or api method in django rest api to search a list by value instead of key

Tags: python, django, api, rest

My list look like this in my model it's a choice list
STATUS_CHOICES = [(DELIVERED_STATUS= 'delivered')
(FEEDBACK_STATUS='feedback')]

DELIVERED_STATUS=1
FEEDBACK_STATUS=2

My endpoint api url is /api/v2/task/list?Status=1

how do i search the content of the list using values of the list instead of their keys for example: /api/v2/task/list?Status=1 to /api/v2/task/list?Status=feedback

Comment: Can you share your relevant code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.